# Ant design Collapse - expand / collapse all button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, antd

How can I have a button triggering an ant.design Collapse component to expand all its tabs, or collapse all of them? I tried changing defaultActiveKey but I get the impression that this can only be changed when the page is rendered? If not, could someone provide a short snippet of a button collapsing multiple panels? The number of panels I have is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use component in controlled mode, that is you should supply value of panels which are open. For that  you should use `activeKey` prop. Here is example:

```
let App = () => {
  let [openPanels, setOpenPanels] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <Collapse activeKey={openPanels} onChange={setOpenPanels}>
      <Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1">
        <p>test1</p>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="This is panel header 2" key="2">
        <p>test2</p>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="This is panel header 3" key="3">
        <p>test3</p>
      </Panel>
    </Collapse>
  );
};
```

Now you can easily add a button and on click set `setOpenPanels([])` to collapse all of them.

Comment: Thanks this is almost there. I marked the answer as correct, but I then realised that this button actually breaks the panels: when I click on the individual panels I can no longer toggle them.

Comment: @yldm it works here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tgilbi, isn't it?

Comment: Not if you add expand / collapse buttons and you click on them. That snippet does not have these buttons.

Comment: @yldm Then it depends what code you have inside those expand/collapse buttons, I can't say without looking at full example

Comment: following your example, I created a handler for the expand / collapse button which calls either setOpenPanels([]) to collapse or setOpenPanels(arr) to expand. The number of panels is fixed. From reading online a bit more it looks like perhaps this is not possible, or not with activeKey?

Comment: @yldm I have updated the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tgilbi, it works, isn't it?

Comment: thanks a lot this works! I believe I tried something very similar but probably had something slightly wrong. Thanks again!